# Update a column value using subquery with an IF

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to update a table with several varchar columns using ORACLE version 11:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE SET PARAMS = 
                        '{ '
                        ||'params:{p1: {'                            
                        ||'p2:\"'                             || P2                           ||'\",'                                   
                        ||'p3:\"'                             || P3                           ||'\",'                                       
                        ||'p4:\"'                             || P4                           ||'\",'
                        ||'p5: [\"'                           || PROBLEM_HERE                 ||'\"],'
                        ||'}}}'
WHERE P6='1';
```

In the "PROBLEM_HERE" variable I need to place a string like "F1", "F2", "F3","F4" or "F1" or "F3" or even ""...

So I made an IF statement to build that string:

```
IF P7 != 0 THEN
   pvalues := '\"'|| op1  ||'\"';
   IF P8 != 0 THEN
         pvalues := pvalues || ',\"'|| op2  ||'\"';
         IF AG_PERM_MOVER_RESELLER != 0 THEN
                 pvalues := pvalues || ',\"'|| op3  ||'\"';
                 IF AG_PERMI_AUTO_EDIT != 0 THEN
                        pvalues := pvalues || ',\"'|| op4  ||'\"';
                 END IF;
         END IF;
    END IF;    
END IF;
```

Any idea how I can place that if inside the update?
Cursor only?

Comment: The SQL equivalent of IF is `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare
  pvalues varchar2(4000);
  p7 number;
  p8 number;
  op1 varchar2(40);
  op2 varchar2(40);
  op3 varchar2(40);
  op4 varchar2(40);
  ag_perm_mover_reseller number;
  ag_permi_auto_edit     number;
begin
  -- do you if here
  if p7 != 0 
  then
    pvalues := '\"'|| op1  ||'\"';
    if p8 != 0 
    then
      pvalues := pvalues || ',\"'|| op2  ||'\"';
      if ag_perm_mover_reseller != 0 
      then
        pvalues := pvalues || ',\"'|| op3  ||'\"';
        if ag_permi_auto_edit != 0 
        then
          pvalues := pvalues || ',\"'|| op4  ||'\"';
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;    
  end if;

  -- do your update here
UPDATE  example_table 
SET     params = '{ '
                 ||'params:{p1: {'                            
                 ||'p2:\"'   || p2       ||'\",'                                   
                 ||'p3:\"'   || p3       ||'\",'                                       
                 ||'p4:\"'   || p4       ||'\",'
                 ||'p5: [\"' || pvalues  ||'\"],'
                 ||'}}}'
WHERE   p6='1';

  commit;
exception 
  when others then
    rollback;
    -- do something about the error
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand what the "PROBLEM_HERE" variable is, but presuming your IFs do what you want, you could nest CASE conditions as follows:

```
with example_table_set (p7, p8, ag_perm_mover_reseller, ag_permi_auto_edit, op1, op2, op3, op4) as (
select 1, 2, 3, 4, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'from dual union all
select 1, 2, 0, 4, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'from dual union all
select 0, 2, 3, 4, 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O' from dual 
) --
select case when p7 != 0
            then '\"'|| op1  ||'\"' || 
                 case when p8 != 0
                      then ',\"'|| op2  ||'\"' ||
                           case when ag_perm_mover_reseller != 0
                                then ',\"'|| op3  ||'\"' ||
                                     case when ag_permi_auto_edit != 0
                                          then ',\"'|| op4  ||'\"'
                                          end
                                end
                      end
            end
from example_table_set;
```

Simply replace it PROBLEM_HERE for the nested case in your update, as in:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE SET PARAMS = 
                        '{ '
                        ||'params:{p1: {'                            
                        ||'p2:\"'                             || P2                           ||'\",'                                   
                        ||'p3:\"'                             || P3                           ||'\",'                                       
                        ||'p4:\"'                             || P4                           ||'\",'
                        ||'p5: [\"'                           || case when p7 != 0
                                                                      then '\"'|| op1  ||'\"' || 
                                                                           case when p8 != 0
                                                                                then ',\"'|| op2  ||'\"' ||
                                                                                     case when ag_perm_mover_reseller != 0
                                                                                          then ',\"'|| op3  ||'\"' ||
                                                                                               case when ag_permi_auto_edit != 0
                                                                                                    then ',\"'|| op4  ||'\"'
                                                                                                    end
                                                                                          end
                                                                                end
                                                                      end                 ||'\"],'
                        ||'}}}'
WHERE P6='1';
```

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. Create a Pl/SQL anonymous block like:

```
declare
  pvalues VARHCAR2(4000);
begin
  -- do you if here

  -- do your UPDATE here
  UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE 
  SET PARAMS = pvalues
  WHERE P6='1';

  COMMIT;
exception 
  when others then
    rollback;
    -- do something about the error
end;
/
```

Comment: and how does the 'if' iterate throught the lines? the way you refer it is out of the update.